# Delete cookie from browser?

Tags: php, http, browser, cookies

Is there any way of instructing a web browser to completely **delete** one's cookie set with PHP?

I do not want to *expiry* it or wait for the browser to be *closed*.

With delete I mean to actually not have it listed inside the cookie's list anymore.

Comment: You may "politely ask" the browser to delete the cookie by setting its value to an empty string, or setting the expiration time to some date in the past, or using `$cookie->delete();` from https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot force the browser to delete the file associated with any cookie, because you can't guarantee there's actually such a file - the contract between browser and web server regarding cookies is that the data will be presented at eligible requests.

You state that you "don't want to wait for the cookie to expire", but cookie expiration is the correct method for indicating that the data is no longer needed and should not be presented on future requests, which in most cases does translate to the browser removing the file.

To delete a cookie, therefore, set its expiration time into the past. In PHP, this is done with [`setcookie()`](http://us.php.net/setcookie).

Comment: This was the closest of the answers (paragraph #1 that is). Thx.

Answer (score 19):

Try something like this to delete all cookies:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
    setcookie($name, '', 1);
}
```

The value `1` is the *expire* value and it represents one second after the begin of the Unix time epoch. So it’s always already expired.

Comment: Someone went and downvoted all the answers that had to do with Expiring, since the question said they don't want to expire it.

Comment: @Chacha102: Well, then that someone doesn’t now how cookies work.

Comment: @Gumbo Or you can improvise and wrap this answer of yours in a function called `deleteAllCookies` to fake it for that someone. :P

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use `setcookie()` and set the expiration date for the cookie you wish to delete to a time in the past. The user's browser should automatically remove it as a result.

Answer (score 3):

'Seems that deleting a cookie is more difficult than it looks.

```
setcookie($name, '', 1);
```

Won't do the trick.  The `''` is empty and `setcookie` can ignore the whole instruction.

Also setting the time to the past sometimes allows the cookie to retain the value whose expire time is newer than 1.

I am dealing with this right now.  I don't know where it comes from, but it's there.

I've resorted to

```
setcookie($name, '0', 9000000000);
```

This ensures the cookie is set to a value that resolves to false and that it is newer than any previous value.

If anyone has any insight into this behavior please tell.

I suspect the difficulty lies in the fact that the domain and path values for `setcookie` are guaranteed to be the same from execution to execution when the values are not specified.

And I am aware such a cookie will not expire until 2038 or so.

Alternately, if the newest expiration date of the cookie is known, it need be set only 1 second after.

Comment: In my case, the reason why setcookie did not work is because I did not use the same location for the fourth parameter. So make sure you use the same location for the 4th parameter, in order to delete cookie successfully

Comment: I found that you have to set the same parameters for setting and deleting the cookie. Set Cookie: setcookie($name, $uid', $time, '/', '', 0); - Delete Cookie: setcookie($name, $uid', 1, '/', '.domain.name', 0); won't work, the 5th parameter must be the same for both.

Comment: Print $_COOKIE array, unset perticular key: unset($_COOKIE[$name]);

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to use combined approach:

- set expiration way back in the past (as suggested by Chacha102)
- use JavaScriptto delete entries from document.cookie DOM object (as suggested by andres descalzo)

There are 2 good reasons for going with mixed approach:

- JavaScript can be disabled in the browser
- not all cookies are visible in document.cookie Some modern browsers are supporting httponly flag for cookies. PHP has support for httponly cookies, see http://www.php.net/setcookie

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this plugin for me and works correctly.

```
(function($) {
    $.cookieAllDelete = function(doc)
    {
        var cookie_date = new Date();
        var cookies = null;

        cookies = doc.cookie.split(';');
        cookie_date.setTime(cookie_date.getTime() - 1);

        for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
        {
            var cookie_name = cookies[i].split('=')[0];
            try {
                if (cookie_name.length > 0)
                    doc.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
            } catch(ex) {}
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery.cookieAllDelete(document);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was also looking tags jQuery and I am confused. thanks for down