# php cookie in firefox will not expire

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have a simple login setup, where I use a cookie to store a login ID #, and with this ID, username and other information can be displayed.

So in order to logout, I run the following php script to log out:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
setcookie("id","",1);
}
header("Location: redirectpage.html");
exit;
?>
```

Which basically expires the cookie.  However, when I arrive at the redirect page, which has the following code:

```
If (isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
//display "You are logged in already"
} else {
// show login form
}
```

It says I am still logged in, and moving to a different pages still says I am logged in, and displaying the cookie value gives me an actual value, meaning the cookie has not expired.  I must be missing something here, but why has the cookie not expired?

Note: I changed the expiration date from time()-60 or some value to 1, but this did not change anything, and removing the if statement to just expire the cookie every time the php code runs still does not do the trick.

Comment: You cannot delete a cookie directly. You set an expiration date in the past and leave it to the browser to delete it. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267341/delete-cookie-from-browser

Comment: @ZombieHunter, `setcookie` takes a unix timestamp as the 3rd argument. A value of 1 *is* in the past.

Comment: What do you have in the cookie? If I create a new cookie in my computer and set it to `id=1`, will I be logged in automatically in your site? Lesson 1: never **ever** trust user-supplied data, including `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE` and some values of `$_FILES` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_*']`

Comment: Carlos, that is not how my login works, the id is an 11-digit number, and if the number is not valid, it will not log you in

Comment: ZombieHunter, you are right, what I meant was expiring it, so the browser cannot access the value anymore.  The 1, based on my research, means that it is set to one second after the year 1970 begins, a past date

Comment: There is a problem with your cookie login method. If the users machine is left unattended somebody could actually steal the cookie and log into his account. A cookie is only a string held in the browser. I would only have to copy that string and then re-created it on my computer to log into the users account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are trying to delete the cookie using the same parameters you used to create it. From the php manual, http://gr2.php.net/setcookie, under "common pitfalls":

> Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set
>   with. If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all
>   other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie
>   with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This
>   is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration
>   time to one year in past.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but do you mean that if I set the cookie as such: setcookie(name, value, expire, "/", ""), I cannot delete it as: setcookie(name, value, newexpire)?  I actually added the last two arguments, and it worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, you must have the same parameters. Don't forget to mark the answer that suits you as "solved" by clicking on the "tick"

Answer (score 0):

Try using if(!empty($_COOKIE... Because isset() considers empty strings to be set. See this table: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php